# Android Keyboard causing PhoneGap App to distort/zoom awkwardly

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

The easiest way to explain what's happening is to show it:

Before the keyboard opens: http://imageshack.us/a/img24/3285/by8h.png

I've drawn a red box around the area that's getting distorted.

After the keyboard closes: http://imageshack.us/a/img27/454/6nbv.png

Looking at the same area (also boxed), an area of the app is distorted. It looks like it's been zoomed in on, and was unable to zoom out.

I originally thought the issue was being caused because the keyboard was compressing the app when it opened, but I adjusted the AndroidManifest.xml to prevent the keyboard from resizing the app window and `<head>` section of my index.html file to prevent the page from zooming.

Here's the `<application>` tag of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="Craps" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I'd originally had `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, but that didn't solve the issue, and I saw someone suggest using `adjustNothing` instead. I hadn't noticed any difference in the performance of the app, so I left `adjustNothing`.

And here's the `<meta>` tag I put in the `<head>` of my index.html to prevent zooming:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

One thing I did notice was that when the buffer `<div>` scrolls (which happens on `y-overflow`), it all resizes and fixes itself. I thought that hiding/showing the areas affected by the zoom might resolve the issue, but that didn't work either.

Also, just as a result of how I built the engine, that table gets emptied and rebuilt anytime that a bet gets placed/wins/loses, so the table is constantly updating/changing, but that area of the app stays zoomed until the buffer scrolls.

Something that stands out in my mind, but I'm not sure if it has anything to do with it, is the thing in the center of the distorted area is the only image in that area of the page. The other headings of that table are FontAwesome icons. Might that have something to do with it?

Any help in tracking down what could be causing this or with possible solutions would be greatly appreciated!

If I can provide any more information to help track this issue down, please don't hesitate to ask!

To see the game working/playing as it should (it actually works *really* well in Chrome on tablets), it's up at `http://duleone.com/craps/`, which is why this zoom thing baffles me.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en?hl%3Den#!topic/phonegap/WgUms65c1UI ... this is a link to a more fleshed out (and more screen caps to show what's happening) version of this question

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this line in the html head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

And perhaps put this in the config.xml:

```
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
```